# Touchscreen X and Y axis switched

Tags: windows, drivers, touchscreen, axis

i have a chinise  DELONG DL070IA touchscreen that i bought from ebay a long time ago. I connected it to a windows 10 pc via USB. Everything worked except when i move my finger up and down the cursor moves left and right. I didn't install any drivers, because i coundn't find any. I found a place that sells it [here](http://www.weiku.com/products/14198057/7_Inch_In_Dash_One_Din_Touch_Monitor_with_VGA_for_Car_PC.html) . When i try to calibrate it through windows it makes the cursor jump around. Is there a way to switch the X and Y axis for the screen?
are there any universal drivers with settings?

Answer (score 0):

put a wireless mouse in using dongle - that will work correctly (even though touch is inverted) then go to control panel display settings, then change from 'Landscape' to 'Landscape flipped' (or portrait if you wish). it will flip it the correct way.